# Language corrections

Tags: discussion, english

I'm from Germany.  I've been living in 4 different countries (speaking 4 different languages) during the past 5 years, just to give you a note on my knowledge of foreign languages.

I think a proper usage of language is a kind of a way of showing respect to the natives, though the way I am forming a sentence, using the English language's grammar will differ from the way natives will do it. Frankly spoken, even if I did want to express myself in an eloquent way, I couldn't, as it's just not my mother tongue.

I don't want to note that on every answer I post. It wouldn't fit to SO rules at all, and it would be nonsense. I've been coding for a year now. Even though the questions I've answered might be answerable by someone else I think that I can help  other people.

I often have the feeling that if I just would be able to explain the answer to someone's question in a language I'm really capable of speaking, my answer would be much more helpful.

What should I do then?

**Why is there no translation queue in the review queue list? This would make it an international effort.**

Comment: Given some of the English I've seen on SO, I'd say you were plenty eloquent enough. Code generally speaks for itself anyway.

Comment: @TJennings thanks, you're totally right. but that's a comparison everybody wins who is capable of writing 'hello'... I've bolded the part of the question I'm interested in specifically.

Comment: If I have a post where I think something is wrong with the grammar or wording I ask in a chat room for a proof-read.

Comment: You are not posting an answer for the OP's benefit.  That's just one person.  It is the next many thousands of googlers that will read it that benefit from it.  Of course you can have no idea what native language they speak.

Comment: The main SO site is an English language site. Language translations are appropriate when there are language-specific SO locations available (such as Portugese SO), but not on the main site at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To the main question - why there's no translation queue here - well, there could be two reasons.

First, Stack Overflow is English-only.  I absolutely respect that English may not be one's native language, but it's the language that the majority of us understand and communicate in.

Second, translation is a tricky road because it cuts both ways:

- If you translate a post to English (or back into the native language), we can't verify beyond a shadow of a doubt that something wasn't lost in translation, and
- There's no guarantee that a non-English speaker will understand an English answer.

There have been a whole slew of internationalized Stack Overflow sites coming up lately.  If you're interested in that, then you should throw your support behind those, or propose a new one if your particular language isn't there.

Comment: The OP may not understand a English answer, _and_ he may not be able to answer questions people have about the OP's problem, that have to be answered to clarify the OP.

Comment: @Cerbrus Is that two different uses of OP? Original Poster (the person) and Original Post (the question). Or something else?

Comment: @BillWoodger: Eh, yea. In order of appearance: user, user/question, question.

Comment: @Cerbrus OK. Thanks. Do you mind if I consider that a little confusing?

Comment: Nah, looking back at it, I could've worded it a little better.